# How to do a natural sort on an NSArray?

Tags: objective-c, sorting, cocoa

I have an array of objects and I need them sorted by their "title" key. It's currently working, though it's using an ASCII sort instead of a natural sort. The titles are filenames, so they look like this:

file1
file2
file3
...
file10
file11
file12

I'm getting, as you would expect:

file1
file10
file11
file12
file2
file3
...

Does anyone know if there is a way built-in to the NSArray sorting functionality to get this natural sorting as opposed to the alphabetical sort? I found some generic algorithms, but I was hoping for something built-in.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9509181/1224741

Answer (score 54, accepted):

`NSString`s can be [compared](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#jumpTo_30) using the [NSNumericSearch](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSNumericSearch) compare option.

One version:

```
NSInteger sort(Obj* a, Obj* b, void*) {
    return [[a title] compare:[b title] options:NSNumericSearch];
}

result = [array sortedArrayUsingFunction:&sort context:nil];
```

Or a bit more generic:

```
NSInteger sort(id a, id b, void* p) {
    return [[a valueForKey:(NSString*)p] 
            compare:[b valueForKey:(NSString*)p]
            options:NSNumericSearch];
}

result = [array sortedArrayUsingFunction:&sort context:@"title"]
```

Or using blocks:

```
result = [array sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(Obj* a, Obj* b) { 
    return [[a title] compare:[b title] options:NSNumericSearch]; 
}];
```

Answer (score 25):

Those attempting to replicate the Finder's sorting behavior on Mac OS X 10.6 and later and iOS 4 and later can use [`localizedStandardCompare:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1409742-localizedstandardcompare?language=objc)
 as the comparator selector.

Those with the same goal on earlier versions of Mac OS X and/or iOS should use [the solution described in the String Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/SearchingStrings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000149-SW1).

Comment: All of the links are broken.

Answer (score 4):

Based on @PeterHosey's answer, if you're working with an array of string objects:

SHORT ANSWER:

```
NSArray *orderedTitles = [unorderedTitles sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)];
```

---

FULL EXAMPLE:

```
NSArray *unorderedTitles = @[
    @"file12",
    @"file1",
    @"file10",
    @"file3",
    @"file2",
    @"file11"
];

NSArray *orderedTitles = [unorderedTitles sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)];
NSLog(@"orderedTitles = %@", orderedTitles);
/*
orderedTitles = (
    file1,
    file2,
    file3,
    file10,
    file11,
    file12
)
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

This works on iOS

```
NSString *name0 = @"winter";
NSString *name1 = @"summer";
CFComparisonResult result = CFStringCompareWithOptions(
    (CFStringRef) name0,
    (CFStringRef) name1,
    CFRangeMake (0, CFStringGetLength((CFStringRef) name0)),
    kCFCompareCaseInsensitive | kCFCompareLocalized | kCFCompareNumerically
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do the sorting in the following way:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"title" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)];
NSArray *sortedItems = [unsortedItems sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];
```