# Sort NSArray with multiple NSDictonaries in it

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I need to sort the given "document" array with "lastname". Here is the sample json

```
document [
{
    id:"100"
    person :{
       name : {
        firstname : "xyz",
        lastname  : "oops"
       },
       photourl: "photo-url"
    }
},
{
    id:"200"
    person :{
       name : {
        firstname : "xyz",
        lastname  : "oops"
       },
       photourl: "photo-url"
    }
}]
```

---

it has an dict "name" inside one more dict "person" and we need to sort with lastname first n then with lastname

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9509181/1059705 check this out.. might help you

Comment: could your please check my edited question,

Comment: Finally i got the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSSortDescriptor *lastNameDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"lastname " ascending:YES] ;
NSArray *sortedArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:lastNameDescriptor];
sortedArray = [myArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

[for more clear description and code check this link, its very easy and perfect, Cheers :)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/SortDescriptors/Articles/Creating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001845-BAJEAIEE)

Comment: This does not compile (because sortDescriptors is nowhere defined) and is *not correct*, because "lastname" is a key inside the "person" dictionay.

Comment: ***I*** don't want anything. I just noticed that the answer is wrong.

Comment: its just a hint brother. use link below it will surely help you. i have also done by same link.

Answer (score 0):

So assuming you put your JSON into an array called "people":

```
NSArray *people = myArrayFromJSON;

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"person" ascending:YES comparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
    NSString *lastName1 = [obj1 valueForKey:@"lastname"];
    NSString *lastname2 = [obj2 valueForKey:@"lastname"];

    return [lastName1 compare:lastname2];
}];

NSArray *sortedArray = [people sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];
```

That'll do it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below given logic

```
for (NSMutableDictionary *document in documents) {
    NSString *lastName = [[document valueForKey:@"person"] valueForKey:@"lastname"];
    [documents setObject:lastName forKey:@"lastnameDescriptor"];
}

NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"lastnameDescriptor" ascending:YES];
NSMutableArray *sortedNames = [documents sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:descriptor]];

for (NSMutableDictionary *document in sortedNames) {
    [document removeObjectForKey:@"lastnameDescriptor"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are close but either needlessly complicated or a little off.

```
NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"person.lastName" ascending:YES];
sortedArray = [document sortedArrayUSingDescriptors:@[descriptor]];
```

(The selector says "key," but if you read the docs, it's actually a keypath, so this will work as expected.)

Answer (score 0):

Lots of almost right answers but none that consider that 'name' is itself a nested dictionary in your document. So I think what you want is:

```
NSSortDescriptor *lastNameDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithkey:@"person.name.lastname" ascending:YES];
NSSortDescriptor *firstNameDescriptor = [NSSorteDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"person.name.firstname" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortedArray = [document sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[lastNameDescriptor, firstNameDescriptor]];
```

Comment: Thanks Erik H. this code worked. but how come string "person.name.lastname" is compared with dictionary keypath value