# iOS filter array of dictionary base on value and not the key

Tags: ios, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have array with dictionaries like this:

```objective-c
Array: (
 {
customerUS= {
 DisplayName = "level";
 InternalName = "Number 2";
 NumberValue = 1;
 },
 customerCAN= {
 DisplayName = "PurchaseAmount";
 InternalName = "Number 1";
 NumberValue = 3500;
 };
}
)
```

I want to filter the dictionaries base on particular value and not the key. For example I want all the dictionaries with values on any key of 3500. Does any body knows how can I do this?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: [I suspect the answer you seek can be found in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/958622/using-nspredicate-to-filter-an-nsarray-based-on-nsdictionary-keys), but I'm not going to investigate too deeply enough to decide to mark your question as a duplicate.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann in the link you have there is filtering by key and I don't want that or need that. I need to filter by value

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9509181/1224741

Comment: possible duplicate of [ios sorting array of dictionaries by key of inner dictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9509138/ios-sorting-array-of-dictionaries-by-key-of-inner-dictionary)

Answer (score 0):

Try a predicate format like:

```
@"%@ IN SELF", testValue
```

When you filter the array each will be run against the `IN`. When you pass `IN` a dictionary it uses the values of the dictionary.

Comment: NSPredicate *myPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ in self", @"3500"]; but doen't work.

Comment: Your question actually shows an array of dictionaries of dictionaries, is that accurate (it doesn't look like a log output)?

Comment: this is the out I'm getting

Comment: If you have nested dictionaries, what should the filter result be? And how many dictionaries are in the outer array?

Comment: if the dictionary has 3500 on any key it should be true

Comment: That isn't a valid answer. What should the array contain. Show an example input and expected output. You have multiple dictionaries, you need to be more clear and specific.

Comment: As I said in my original post. I'm looking for way to filter the dictionaries where any key contains 3500

Answer (score 0):

you can also use

```
-keysOfEntriesPassingTest:
```

of NSDictionary. Just pass in a block like so:

```
for(NSDictionary *myDictionary in myArray){ 
    NSSet *resultSet = [myDictionary keysOfEntriesPassingTest:^(id key, id object, BOOL *stop) {
        //assuming that 3500 is an int, otherwise use appropriate condition.
        if([[NSNumber numberWithInt:object] isEqual:[NSNumber numberWithInt:3500]]){
            return YES;
        }else{
            return NO;
        }
     }];
    if (resultSet.count>0){
        //do whatever to myDictionary
    }
}
```