# filteredArrayUsingPredicate doesn't filter data

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, nsmutablearray, nspredicate

I am developing iOS app, in which i have searchBar.

What i want is,

**when user types `s` in the searchBar, i want to get all the `Merchant_Name` who starting with letter `s` from my array**

Here is my code snippet i have tried but it is not working,

My arr contains:

```
 arr at index 0 = {
        "Merchant_Id" = 1261;
        "Merchant_Name" = "Magazine Mall";
        "Merchant_Url" = "magazine-mall";
    },
     arr at index 1 =   {
        "Merchant_Id" = 1262;
        "Merchant_Name" = MakeMyTrip;
        "Merchant_Url" = makemytrip;
    },
   arr at index 2 =     {
        "Merchant_Id" = 1263;
        "Merchant_Name" = Travelguru;
        "Merchant_Url" = travelguru;
    },
    arr at index 3 =    {
        "Merchant_Id" = 1266;
        "Merchant_Name" = Travelchacha;
        "Merchant_Url" = travelchacha;
    },
      arr at index 4 =  {
        "Merchant_Id" = 1267;
        "Merchant_Name" = Tradus;
        "Merchant_Url" = tradus;
    },
    arr at index 5 =    {
        "Merchant_Id" = 1268;
        "Merchant_Name" = ToyWorld;
        "Merchant_Url" = toyworld;
    },
     arr at index 6 =   {
        "Merchant_Id" = 1269;
        "Merchant_Name" = Topskin;
        "Merchant_Url" = topskin;
    },
   ....
```

Code:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Merchant_Name LIKE[cd] %@ ",searchText];
NSMutableArray *filter1 =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
filter1 = [[arr filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate] mutableCopy];
NSLog(@"predicate  = %@ -------  filter=%@",predicate,filter1);
```

Log Shows:

```
predicate  = Merchant_Name LIKE[cd] "s" -------  filter=(
)
```

Please help me, Where i am doing mistake?

***Thanks in advance.***

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9509138/ios-sorting-array-of-dictionaries-by-key-of-inner-dictionary-and-showing-respect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSPredicate *predicate =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name beginswith[c] %@", searchText];

NSMutableArray *filter1 =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
filter1 = [[arr filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate] mutableCopy];
NSLog(@"predicate  = %@ -------  filter=%@",predicate,filter1);
```

more understand follow this

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/predicates/Articles/pUsing.html

Comment: After doing this how do i filter it ?

Answer (score 1):

Change your LIKE for BeginsWith

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Merchant_Name beginswith[c] %@ ",searchText];
NSMutableArray *filter1 =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
filter1 = [[arr filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate] mutableCopy];
NSLog(@"predicate  = %@ -------  filter=%@",predicate,filter1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Merchant_Name beginswith %@", [searchText uppercaseString]];
```

Comment: I want only name starting with letter not CONTAINS

Comment: [ANY name LIKE[c] %@]

Comment: After doing this how do i filter it ?