# Is there a way to set an int to 001

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

i need to set an integer to start from 001 instead of only 1

```
int iNumber = 001;
NSLog(@"%d",iNumber); // this is logging 1 instead of 001
```

is there a possible way to make it 001 ?

[UPDATED]

i need this because i`m creating an NSMutableArray from NSUserDefaults, after that I'm sorting the array using NSSortDescriptor. the problem is because i can't set the int to start from 001 the array i sorted like this 0, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9.

More Code explained

```
NSString *name = @"Name";
NSUserDefaults *MainArray = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *Temp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d", name,MainNumber];
[MainArray setObject:@"test" forKey:Temp];
[MainArray synchronize];
NSLog(@"%@",Temp);
MainNumber++;
```

the above code will save it like this : Name1,Name2,Name3....

i need it to be Name001, Name002, Name003 .......

thank you in advance :)

Comment: Please expand on why you want this behavior, or what exactly you want.  In integer terms `001 == 1`.

Comment: You are confusing _value_ with _appearance_. An `int` has a _value_ that can be _displayed_ in different ways. Some of the many ways to display the value `1` are: "001", "0x1", "1", "10e0". `int i = 1;` sets the value of `i` to "001".

Comment: You say something about sorting an NSMutableArray but you don't show any code related to sorting or to a NSMutableArray. You should check if this related post does what you want : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846301/how-to-do-a-natural-sort-on-an-nsarray

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use %03d format specifier, e.g.

```
NSString *theString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@%03d",name,MainNumber];
NSLog(@"%03d", iNumber );// can also use in nsstring stringWithFormat
```

The Objective-C way,

```
 NSNumberFormatter * numberFormatter = [[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
 [numberFormatter setPaddingPosition:NSNumberFormatterPadBeforePrefix];
 [numberFormatter setPaddingCharacter:@"0"];
 [numberFormatter setMinimumIntegerDigits:10];

 NSNumber * number = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];
 NSString * theString = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:number];

 NSLog(@"%@", theString);
```

Now your requiremnet:

```
 NSString *name = @"Name";
 NSUserDefaults *MainArray = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
 NSString *Temp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%03d", name,MainNumber];
 [MainArray setObject:@"test" forKey:Temp];
 [MainArray synchronize];
 NSLog(@"%@",Temp);
 MainNumber++;
```

Comment: what i really need is to set the integer to 001 not the logging results :)

Comment: All you accomplish is creating a string with the value "001". Instead of doing all that you did, you could simply do this: `NSString *theString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"001"];`. No offense, but your code is very excessive and not what the OP wants.

Comment: NSString *theString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%03d",iNumber];

Comment: @qegal the original answer is exactly what the op wanted, you create a string that will be nsloged as 001 - 002 etc etc. the op could just create this string and append it as a string directly to name the file. the updated answer is more efficient tho.

Answer (score 0):

You're attacking the problem from too low a level. To create a sort descriptor that will sort the string `@"10"` after the strings `@"2"`, `@"3"`, `@"4"`, etc., tell it to compare strings using [`localizedStandardCompare:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-SW88), which

> should be used whenever file names or other strings are presented in lists and tables where Finder-like sorting is appropriate.

```
[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:theKey
                              ascending:YES
                               selector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)];
```

Answer (score -3):

You could use a 'float'

```
float *float = 001;
```

This *may* need tweaking as I am on my iPad, so I don't have Xcode to verify...

Comment: /glares/ I am using CR with gcc, it generates one *warning*