# Keep leading zeros when converting NSString to Integer

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring

Is there a way to keep the leading zeros when converting a string to an integer. For example say the string was "01" is there a way i could store it as an integer value of 01?

```
- (int) getNextHand{

    int temp = [[numbersArray objectAtIndex:cardsDelt] intValue]; 
    NSLog(@"Card %i: %i", cardsDelt, temp);
    cardsDelt++;
    return temp;
}
```

My numbersArray contains 4 leading zero numbers they are:
"00"
"01"
"02"
"03"

Comment: Can you clarify why you want leading zeros? Do you just want to *show* it to the user with a leading zero later?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to set an int to 001](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11112201/is-there-a-way-to-set-an-int-to-001)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to log with leading zeroes use something like %02d

Answer (score 2):

Nope integers are numbers and `01` will be automatically be converted to `1`

Answer (score 1):

`01` and `1` are two representations of the same integer value.  If the leading digits contain information, then you have a string, not an integer.

Comment: Ok thanks. I can see a way around the problem thanks for your clarification.