# Sort NSArray based on multiple properties

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, nsarray

Here's the problem i have :- 
I have an array

```
Item1,
Item2,
Item3,
Item4,
Item5,
Item6,
Item7,
....,Item11
```

I need to sort this array in that specific order ,ofcourse all the values are of type 'NSString'

if i use

```
sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)
```

it sorts it like this:-

```
Item1,
Item10,
Item11,
Item2,
Item3,
Item4,
Item5,
Item6,
Item7,
Item8,
Item9
```

I can manually extract the numeric value from this but i thought there may be a better way to do this perhaps by using 'NSComparator'.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to do a natural sort on an NSArray?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846301/how-to-do-a-natural-sort-on-an-nsarray)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use it like this:

```
NSArray *arry = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Item1",@"Item2",@"Item3",@"Item4",@"Item5",@"Item11",@"Item10",@"Item6", nil];
NSArray *sortedStrings = [arry sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)];
NSLog(@"sortedStrings---%@",sortedStrings);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSInteger sortFile(id a, id b, void* context) {
    return [a compare:b options:NSNumericSearch];
}

[yourArray sortedArrayUsingFunction:mySort context:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

This code works for me:

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Item1",
                  @"Item10",
                  @"Item11",
                  @"Item2",
                  @"Item3", nil];

array = [array sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSString *str1, NSString *str2) {
    return [str1 compare:str2 options:(NSNumericSearch)];
} ];

NSLog(@"%@", array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 NSArray *sortedStrings = [yourArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)];
```

For more [sortedArrayUsingSelector](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can implement whatever function you want if you do it using [sortedArrayUsingFunction:context:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/sortedArrayUsingFunction%3acontext%3a)