# iOS: natural sort order

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchrequest, natural-sort

I have an app for iOS that uses Core Data to save and retrieve data.
How would I fetch data sorted by a field of NSString type in **natural sort order**?

Right now the result is:

```
100_title
10_title
1_title
```

I need:

```
1_title
10_title
100_title
```

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846301/how-to-do-a-natural-sort-on-an-nsarray).

Comment: @dandan78 thanks a lot. But Comparators not supported on Core Data for iOS. "NSSortDescriptor (comparator blocks are not supported)". Is there a way to give Core Data a hint to sort a field with NSNumericSearch flag?

Comment: @surlac: Have a look at Peter Hosey's answer to that question: You can  use `localizedStandardCompare:` in the Core Data sort descriptor.

Comment: @MartinR, you rock! I've added `localizedStandardCompare:` selector and it is sorted natural way now. Thank you very much! Please put it in a separate answer so I can mark it. I think it would be helpful for SO as a localized for iOS version of the question mentioned above.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [localizedStandardCompare:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/localizedStandardCompare:) as selector in the sort descriptor for the Core Data fetch request, for example

```
NSSortDescriptor *titleSort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"title"
                                  ascending:YES 
                                   selector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[titleSort]];
```

**Swift 3:**

```
let titleSort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "title",
                    ascending: true,
                    selector: #selector(NSString.localizedStandardCompare))
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
```

or better

```
let titleSort = NSSortDescriptor(key: #keyPath(Entity.title),
                    ascending: true,
                    selector: #selector(NSString.localizedStandardCompare))
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
```

where "Entity" is the name of the Core Data managed object subclass.