# Fetching using an array of sort descriptors returns strings out of order, how can I order them correctly?

Tags: core-data, nssortdescriptor

I am trying to return strings containing numbers in order but there are a few places where my current sort descriptors fail (see the code below).  Im trying to return my data by the day number, week number and category.  Here is an example:

```
Day 1, week 1
Day 2, week 1
```

Currently, the sort gets out of order during week 2:

```
Day 10, week 2
Day 11, week 2
Day 8, week 2
Day 9 week 2
```

I tried using the localizedCompare with my last sort descriptor, which didnt help.  Thanks in advance for the help!

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {
    if (!fetchedResultsController ) {
        NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Workouts" inManagedObjectContext:[Utils appDelegate].managedObjectContext];
        [request setEntity:entity];

        NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"w_category" ascending:YES];
        NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor2 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"weekNo"
                                                                        ascending:YES];
        Workouts *changeSort;
        NSString *sortingChoice;

        if ([changeSort.w_scoring isEqualToString:@"scoring"]){
            sortingChoice = @"w_programDay";
        } else if (![changeSort.w_scoring isEqualToString:@"scoring"]){
            sortingChoice = @"w_name";
        }

        NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor3 =[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", sortingChoice] ascending: YES selector: @selector(localizedCompare:)];

        NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDescriptor, sortDescriptor2,sortDescriptor3, nil];
        [request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

        NSFetchedResultsController *newController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"w_category" cacheName:nil];

        newController.delegate = self;
        self.fetchedResultsController = newController;
    }

    return fetchedResultsController;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS: natural sort order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14604503/ios-natural-sort-order) - Use `localizedStandardCompare:` to sort the strings according to their numerical value.

Comment: Thanks Martin! I was using the wrong selector.