# Sorting Numbers Objective C

Tags: objective-c, sorting

I have got an array of strings which i sort using the method

```
[TableViewPopoverList sortUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

The first part of these strings is a number, however for example if string1 = "16 Ag....." and string2 = "8 Ag...." it sorts it as string1 then string2, obviously it sees the 1 and puts it before the 8, What i want to do is have it so it sees the entire number so it sorts string2 then string1.

What is the easiest way of doing this.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to do a natural sort on an NSArray?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846301/how-to-do-a-natural-sort-on-an-nsarray)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do it this way...

```
[TableViewPopoverList sortUsingComparator:^(NSString *obj1, NSString *obj2) {
    return [obj1 compare:obj2 options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch | NSNumericSearch)];
}];
```

This uses the `compare:options:` method on `NSString` and the `NSNumericSearch` option will compare numbers as actual numbers.